MS Access 2016 ODBC Link to SQL Server some data records display #DELETED
I am connecting to SQL Server using ODBC 18 (have also tried 17)
and when I link a table, any records with non English characters in them make the entire row display every field as #DELETED
HOWEVER, if I IMPORT the same table into Access, then it displays everything fine.
I presume there is some form of Collation/Character encoding issue within the connection  itself, but I cannot find anything to change.
FYI the columns in SQL Server are NVARCHAR and the database is using the Latin1_General_CI_AS collation.
Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this please?
Tried ODBC 17 & 18.
Looked through the connection wizard for any possible criteria to change

Didn't you ask this question earlier? Did you delete it and create a duplicate?

I did ask the question, someone else edited it , not quite sure why they would replace words like 'Fields' with 'Columns' though..

Relational databases have columns and rows. "Fields" and "Records" have always sounded more UI to me. But hey, if I understand what you mean, communication is happening, and that's a passing grade.

What's the DDL of the table in SQL Server? Access is known to display #DELETED in rows where it doesn't understand the primary key values in a row, such as with a bigint column where the values have exceeded the int32 range that Access understands.
